# redirectling user to a webpage telling them to download the app in react

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I built a page in react which has multiple buttons that lead to different URLs. One of the buttons opens the app if it is installed on a mobile device.

However if this button is pressed on a web browser on desktop or a device that does not have the app installed, then nothing happens.

How can I redirect users to another page if they do not have the app installed or are on web browser on the desktop.

Below is the button with the

```
<FunkyButton><a href="waterapp://xyz.co.uk" style={{ color: "white" }}>Open App</a></FunkyButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) You need to detect a browser - for example the chrome browser can be achieved with this bit of code: `const isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);`

2) You need client-side routing to get access to browsers history (for example [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start))

Here is a live demo to get you started: https://codesandbox.io/embed/modest-taussig-ctqs1